# loading data caused error in R markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

````
```{r}

data(UCBAdmissions)

total <- NULL

for(i in 1:6) {
  total <- total+UCBAdmissions[,,i]
}

mosaic(total, shade = T)

```
````

I try to do this in Rmd. The script works well as R script, but every time I try to knit PDF, this error shows:
Error: dims4 [product 4] don't match the length of object[0] Execution halted.

I noticed that this error may be caused by long loading time of the dataset, but how to solve it in Rmd?

Comment: You got two commas in Ucb admissions in the for loop

Comment: The two commas aren't the problem. It is an array with three dimensions. The problem is adding `total` a `NULL` object. Try `NULL + array(1,2)` to see.

Answer (score 0):

I should assign some value to total, then the problem will be solved. The error is caused by format of R markdown.